# How to update same field multiple times in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have to update the linkedContacts field multiple times,  delete 1 item and add some new items, so I have written a query:

```
  await Contact.updateOne(
    { _id: secondContact._id },
    {
      $pull: {
        linkedContacts: { contactId: firstContactId },
      },
      $addToSet: { linkedContacts: linkedContacts },
    },
  )
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
ERROR: Updating the path 'linkedContacts' would create a conflict at 'linkedContacts'
```

I don't want to split this query into 2 different queries, so is there a way to do it in a single query?

Comment: You could use an [aggregation pipeline in the update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).